# cancan not recognizing read operations and rejecting messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have routes.rb:

```
resource :account, :only => [:show, :update]
```

In my ability.rb, I have

```
can :read, Account, :id => user.account_id
```

I have defined def update and def show functions in my AccountsController

This configuration gives me 403, Access denied error when I do a GET request for /account. But if I change my ability.rb to

```
can :manage, Account, :id => user.account_id
```

it works fine. Any reason why my :show function is not being mapped to :read?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I figured out what the problem was. So the deal was that I was calling the cancan's authorize! function myself for some constraints on my code, and I was passing something like

```
authorize!("show", @class_obj)
```

But actually CanCan expects a symbol, so the right call should be

```
authorize!(:show, @class_obj)
```

which can be achieved like this:

```
authorize!("show".intern, @class_obj)
```